# ZF2 mysql query with interval

Tags: php, mysql, date, zend-framework2

In my application I want to print a list with members who where online the last 5 minutes.

I tried to create this by mysql interval with the code below;

```
    $interval = 5;
    $select->where(array('member_last_online > ?' => 'SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$interval.' MINUTE)'));
```

Which produce this notice;

```
Notice: Attempting to quote a value without specific driver level support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production environment. in ..zf_path..
```

The output from 'getSqlSTring()' is;

```
SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE member_last_online > 'SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)'
```

If I execute the query below directly on the table it returns the data as accepted:

```
SELECT members.* FROM members WHERE member_last_online > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

What am I do wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to do something like: `$adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier($interval)` have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287731/quote-value-into-zend-framework-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the db platform to `getSqlString()` to avoid the warning (so it knows how to quote values):

```
// assuming $db is the DB adapter instance
echo $select->getSqlString($db->getPlatform());
```

the solution to your main question is:

```
$select->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$interval.' MINUTE)'));
```

or more readably:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression;

$select->where(new Expression('SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$interval.' MINUTE)'));
```

Comment: In my case, 'echo $select->getSqlString($this->getAdapter()->getPlatform())' worked to eliminate warning :)